# How to solve my sluggish code (using PHP - PDO )

Tags: php, pdo

I am using PHP PDO,
this the code :

```
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
  //select room and insert to chart
  $thisDay=date ("Y-m-d");
  $query = $db->prepare("SELECT room FROM d_room WHERE activ=1 ORDER BY room");
  $query->execute();
  for($a = 1; $result = $query->fetch(); $a++) {
    $query2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO d_chart (date,room,status) VALUES (? + INTERVAL ? DAY,?,0)");
    $query2->execute(array($thisDay,$i,$result['room']));
  }
}
```

this code run too slow, How to make better code and fast, < 2 second.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to make this significantly simpler by using an [`INSERT...SELECT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) query (assuming MySQL)

```
// Make sure you see any errors that might occur
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$thisDay = date('Y-m-d');
$stmt = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO d_chart (date, room, status)
    SELECT (:thisDay + INTERVAL :days DAY), room, 0
    FROM d_room WHERE activ = 1'); // there's no need to order these results
$stmt->bindParam(':thisDay', $thisDay);
$stmt->bindParam(':days', $i, PDO::PARAM_INT);
for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

If `d_room.activ` has an index, this would be even faster.

Comment: --> the result is only one day for each room, I expect the next 1000 days for each room. example :  I have 48 rooms, I want to insert 1000 days for each room.

Comment: @danihandiki That's very odd. The query should execute 1000 times due to the `for` loop. You sure you're using my exact code?

Comment: @danihandiki even if the date wasn't incrementing by one day each time, you should have 1000 records for each room, each with the same day.

Comment: @danihandiki also make sure you're able to see any errors if they occur. See my updated answer for an example

Comment: I use Xampp v 3.2.1, php 5.2.0. 
if this effect ?

Comment: thanks a lot. the code work fine, got no error, helpful and useful. sorry I just got wrong file in wrong folder

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why you are trying to do this. However,I suggest you not to store this fuzzy data in your database because there are other ways for doing such tasks if time and space constraint is the issue. As you said <2 seconds then storing that big result will not take less than 30seconds even on the local machine.

So what you can do is just store single result in database as follows:

```
$thisDay=date ("Y-m-d");
$query = $db->prepare("SELECT room FROM d_room WHERE activ=1 ORDER BY room");
$query->execute();
$result = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); // storing result here would reduce some time to fetch the data inside loop because your script would not require to get the data again and again from server.
$query = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO d_chart (date,room,status) VALUES (? + INTERVAL ? DAY,?,0)");
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($result);$i++)
{
  $query->execute(array($thisDay,$i,$result[$i]['room']));
}
```

and if you want to retrieve the data for next 1000 days then just fetch the single day data from the database and show the result using some mathematical calculations for next 1000 days at the client side, which would be much faster than anything.

However, you should explain what is your aim behind doing such huge task so that you can get better answers.

Comment: I learn to make room status sytem. the system inform which rooms are available or empty in the date. if the status = 1 it s mean available

Comment: I will suggest you store the days on which room is not available or available. For example, today is 12-07 and the room is booked for 25-07 then you should only store that 12-07 date and in one another duration column you should store the duration till room would be available from the example it is 13 days so store 13 in duration column. So if user query for the room from 12-07 to next 13 days duration it will result "available" else "unavailable". Or you may think for a better solution.

Comment: Yes you should. If require help you may get from me. :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't run the exact same query 1000 times!
2. Check your indexing to speed up the query.
3. Prepare the query, then execute it in the loop. This is what preparing is for.
4. Use PDO::beginTransaction and PDO::commit before and after the loop, respectively. Index updates can be expensive and it's faster to do them all at once.

That should at least make it as fast as possible.

```
$thisDay = date ("Y-m-d");         // Take this outside the loop
$query   = $db->prepare("SELECT room FROM d_room WHERE activ=1 ORDER BY room");
$query2  = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO d_chart (date,room,status) VALUES (? + INTERVAL ? DAY,?,0)");     //  Prepare this once

$query->execute();               // Just run this once
$rowset = $query->fetchAll ();   //  Put into an array to re-loop without querying again

$db->beginTransaction ();        //  Will update indices in bulk - faster

for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++)
{
    //select room and insert to chart
    foreach ($rowset as $result)
        $query2->execute(array($thisDay,$i,$result['room']));
}
$db->commit ();                   //  Apply changes
```

As you can see, the loop is now much, much tighter - always the first place to look to speed up code.

Comment: Edited - see reviewed answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
    I am not seeing any reason to run this query thousands time inside the loop. Because it is executing the same query. Put the query outside the loop.





    <?php
        //select room and insert to chart
        $thisDay = date("Y-m-d");
        $query   = $db->prepare("SELECT room FROM d_room WHERE activ=1 ORDER BY room");
        $query->execute();
        $query2 = $db->prepare("INSERT INTO d_chart (date,room,status) VALUES (? + INTERVAL ? DAY,?,0)");
$result = $query->fetch();
        for ($i = 0; $i < 1000; $i++) {

            $query2->execute(array($thisDay, $i, $result['room']));

        }
```

Comment: Where does `$result` come from?

Comment: @B. I. Sadi the result is same, just one day for each room, I expect the next 1000 days for each room. example :  I have 48 rooms, I want to insert 1000 days for each room.